Track loading state with zustand
I have a zustand store:
// catsStore.ts

import { create } from 'zustand'

import { getCats } from '@resources/cats' // use fetch to get cats array

type Cat = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

type CatsState = {
  cats: Cat[]
  loading: boolean
}

type CatsActions = {
  getCats: (limit: number, controller: AbortController) => Promise<void>
}

type CatsStore = CatsState & CatsActions

const initialState: CatsState = {
  cats: [],
  loading: false,
}

export const useCatsStore = create<CatsStore>()((set) => ({
  ...initialState,
  getCats: async (limit, controller) => {
    set({loading: true})
    try {
      const cats = await getCats(limit, controller)
      set({cats, loading: false})
    } catch(e) {
      set({cats: [], loading: false})
    }
  }
}))

And a component that uses it:
// Cats.tsx

import { FC, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useCatsStore } from './catsStore'

export const Cats: FC = () => {
  const { getCats, cats, loading } = useCatsStore()

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await getCats(1, controller)
    }

    fetchData()

    return () => {
      controller.abort() // cancel request on unmount
    }
  }, [getCats])

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? 'LOADING' : (
        cats.map(cat => (
          <div key={cat.id}>{cat.name}</div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

Now, on mounting the Cats component, the state changes like this:
{loading: false, cats: []} // initial state
    |
    V
{loading: true, cats: []} // call getCats
    |
    |
    |  // fetching delay, loading is TRUE
    |
    V
{loading: false, cats: [{id: 'aaa', name: 'aaa'}]} // got cats

But in strict mode, React renders the component twice to spot side-effect errors. And this is exactly the case
The getCats action is now called twice. The first request is canceled using controller.abort() and the states sequence is this now:
{loading: false, cats: []} // initial state
    |
    V
{loading: true, cats: []} // first getCats call
    |
    V
{loading: true, cats: []} // second getCats call
    |
    V
{loading: false, cats: []} // catch handler from the first call
    |
    |
    |  // fetching delay from the second call, loading is FALSE
    |
    V
{loading: false, cats: [{id: 'aaa', name: 'aaa'}]} // got cats

In this case, the loading state is not rendered.
Of course I can skip setting the loading state to false on error, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.
May be there are some best practices to track loading state correctly?
UPD:
Finally found out the reason of this behaviour.
The catch statement is just listening for errors and it's not firing synchronously after controller.abort() is called. For this reason the actions sequence is this:
call first getCats
call controller.abort()
call second getCats
catch handler from the first call

and not this:
call first getCats
call controller.abort()
catch handler from the first call
call second getCats

In fact I shouldn't change the state if the component is unmounted and try/catch statement should be like this:
try {
  const cats = await getCats(limit, controller)
  set({cats, loading: false})
} catch(e) {
  if (e instanceof DOMException && e.name === 'AbortError') return
  set({cats: [], loading: false})
}

It works but I'm still looking for a better solution
